# How do I 'install' a module on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Excuse me as I'm new to this. I've done all the searching I can, and while I know the module I want to install, I can't figure out *how* to install the specific module.

I'm wanting to install [Python-OAuth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) to GAE, but as I can't find the specific `oauth2.py` file, I don't know what to copy into my app's directory on my machine (let alone if that will work).

What is the most direct way of installing third-party python modules on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case, copy the entire `oauth2` directory to your app's folder. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

[Modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) in python are nothing but python files. Packages are directories that contain an `__init__.py` file. You can import a python file called foobar.py that resides in the same directory as the file you're importing from like so `import foobar` at which point you will get everything in foobar under the `foobar.` namespace.